# populate UIView Dynamically in a ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I am trying to load in a scrollView a customView dynamically. I have create a custom view(.xib) and I add it as a subview of a new UIView that I am creating in a for loop. It only adds the subView in the last for loop.

I am not sure if this is the most efficient way to do this but I can't figure any other way. I tried to make a copy but it copies the same one.

I looked for similar posts but I didn't find something.

I guess is something easy but I am new in coding.

here is my code.

Thanks
[Picture of problem I am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUgLj.png)

```
import UIKit

class ScrollTableViewCell: UITableViewCell  {


@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

let customView:ViewForScrollView = (Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ViewForScrollView", owner: self, options: nil)!.first as? ViewForScrollView)!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    self.scrollView.delegate = self
    tileView(weatherHours: 4)


}


override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

func tileView(weatherHours : Int){
    let tileWidth : CGFloat = 60
    let tileHeight : CGFloat = 60
    let marginX : CGFloat = 15
    let viewOriginX : CGFloat = 15
    let viewOriginY : CGFloat = 5
    var padding : CGFloat = 0

    for (index) in 1...weatherHours{

        customView.label.text = "\(index)"
        let aView = UIView()
        aView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        aView.addSubview(customView)

        aView.frame = CGRect(x: padding + marginX, y: viewOriginY, width: tileWidth , height: tileHeight)
        padding = padding + tileWidth + 15
        scrollView.addSubview(aView)

    }
    let scrollViewWidth : CGFloat = tileWidth + (padding) + 15
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollViewWidth , height: 80)
    }

}

extension ScrollTableViewCell : UIScrollViewDelegate{

}

extension UIView{
    func copyView() -> UIView{
        return (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: 
NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self)) as? UIView)!
    }
}
```

Comment: The content height needs to be the sum of the views + padding. Also I would recommend using a tableview. You will find it easier I would think.

Comment: This might help you: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch07p360scrollViewInCode/ch20p570scrollViewInCode/ViewController.swift

Comment: The scrollview gets the UIViews as I you can see in the picture but I can't add the customView in each UIView subview . Only the in last one.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UITableView` by pinning properly constraints leading,Trailing,Top and bottom and then set the automatic dimension.

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

> Note: When you set automatic dimension then do not need to implement
>   `heightForRowAtIndex` method

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of time I found a solution.The whole approach was wrong! Here is how I made it and basically the Correct title. for the question "How to add a reusable UIView.xib in a tableViewcell.xib that contains a UIscrollView.xib "

Basically I was missing the "required init" in the UIView class and to instantiate the view also small mistakes with my small experience in programming.

here is the code

https://github.com/NorwegianGR/Reusable-UIView-in-a-ScrollView

Thanks everybody for fast reply !